# Slowly changing dimensions - data integrity

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-key, constraint, slowly-changing-dimension

When using SCD is it possible to still enforce FK contraints. Consider the following table structure:

```
customer (data_version_id PK, customer_id PK, name, address1,...etc)
order(order_id PK, customer_id FK, data_version_id FK, order_no, ....etc)
```

A data version is used as a snapshot of the state of all reference data (e.g. customers, products, suppliers etc) at a given point in time. This allows changes to be made to data without them instantly going live, when all data changes have been checked (usually once a week) they are all pushed out at once. The reference to data_version_id in the order table is basically to store which data_version was used when the order was created. That way we can query what the customers address was at that time, what prices were in place etc.

This currently works well and allows us to enforce contraints ensuring that even if a code fault occurs whereby a query attempts to insert an order for a data version where a customer does not exist (due to a code fault), SQL would error due to the FK relationship.

With data versions in our system incrementing relatively frequently the majority of records in the customer table will simply be duplicated for each data version. We are looking at changing the data structure to more of an SCD structure so we have data_version_start & data_version_end in each reference data table eg:

```
customer (data_version_start PK, data_version_end PK, customer_id PK,  name, address1,...etc)
order(order_id PK, customer_id , data_version_id, order_no, ....etc)
```

This would dramatically reduce the number or records in our customer table as we would only require a record for each change but in doing this we can no longer have an FK constraint from order to customer based on data version allowing the potential of erroneous data along with losing core sql functionality e.g. cascade deletes, removing a customer would require all orders to manually be removed.

Are we missing a trick or is this just a compromise of this approach?

We are using SQL 2008 R2 - but are looking to upgrade to SQL 2014 in the near furture (if this makes any difference).

Comment: Couldn't you accomplish this simply by _not_ incrementing the `data_version_id` unless there is an actual change to the record? If not, how will you handle the same scenario when switching to start and end dates? Something seems unclear here. Once clarified, I can post an answer.

Comment: Its not so much incrementing the data version it is just creating a duplicate record in the next data version. If the record is not created in the next data version it is the same as the customer effectively being deleted from the system. Once the system moves onto a new data version all subsequent entities are created using reference data from the new data version, if the customer does not exist in that data version no orders can be created for them.

Comment: I think that answers my question, if you are saying that there is a system-wide `data_version_id` as opposed to that being a number that can increment per each change, per each entity. If that is the case, then again, how do you plan on handling the "staging" of new data records with start and end dates since there will no longer be a system-wide `data_version_id`?

Comment: Apologies, I didn't really make that clear. The staging data version is the always the top data version. E.g. Say we are staging in data version 10 meaning data version 9 is currently live, we would have a copy of all customer records with a data_version_from = 10 and data_version_to = 10. Then when users are happy with their changes, all from and to records are incremented to 11 and records that have changed would be created as data_version_from = (data_version of last change) and data_version_to = 10. Then the live data version would become 10. Hope that makes sense!